Return a table and an integer in PostgreSQL function
I have this is SQL Server stored procedure:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IMG_IWD_GET_CHQBOOK]
    (@BRANCH_CODE VARCHAR(3),
     @CUSTOMER_NO VARCHAR(15),
     @ACCOUNT_NO  VARCHAR(10),
     @CHEQUE_NO   VARCHAR(6),
     @TXN_CODE    VARCHAR(2))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        START_NO AS CHQ_START_LEAF_NUM,
        END_NO AS CHQ_END_LEAF_NUM,
        PREFIX AS CHQ_PFX_NUM
    FROM 
        MCHEQUEBOOK
    WHERE 
        1 = 1
        AND (BRANCH_CODE = @BRANCH_CODE)
        AND (CUSTOMER_NO = @CUSTOMER_NO)
        AND (ACCOUNT_NO = @ACCOUNT_NO)
        AND (PREFIX = @TXN_CODE)
        AND (@CHEQUE_NO BETWEEN START_NO AND END_NO)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
        RETURN 1;
    ELSE
        RETURN 9;
END;

I want to convert it to a PostgreSQL function or procedure, but this procedure returns two values a table row and an integer if there is a row it will return int 1 and the row else it will return a empty table and int 9 how can I do this in PostgreSQL.
I tried several things like creating a type but it works fine when there is no row if there is a row it returns everything in one column I could not fix this.

This T-SQL should not have been a PROCEDURE in the first place: because it's a single read-only SELECT query with parameters then this should be an inline table-valued function (aka ITVF): CREATE FUNCTION GetIdwChequeBook( @branchCode, etc ) WITH SCHEMABINDING RETURNS TABLE AS SELECT START_NO, FROM MCHEQUEBOOK ;

can you explain bit more I'm new to this field. And how can I do tis in postgresql

Read plpgsql, in particular Declarartions and Returning.
